# Can't find Google_Client.php in Google API PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

The official tutorial on Core Reporting API tells us to include two files:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
```

However, as we can see on the GitHub page (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), there is no `Google_Client.php` file (in fact, I can't find it anywhere inside the folders). Is the official tutorial out of date or something? What can I do?

Comment: Probably outdated, i gave it a look and you should load autoloader.php ``require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';``

Comment: @arma Thanks! Can't believe the mess. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Try below code,Pleae include `autoload.php` file...

```
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php'; 

  $client = new Google_Client();

  $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

  $client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");

  $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
```

Comment: Although I'm trying to use OAuth, `autoload.php` has solved my problem for now.